# How to list subcollection on firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
collection/document/collection/document

user/teamname/username/info
```

I want to list `teamname document`'s collections.I need collection names.  Below functions return undefined.

```
firestore.collection('user')
.doc('teamname').onSnapshot((data) => { console.log(data) });

firestore.collection('user')
.doc('teamname').get().then((data) => { console.log(data) });
```

log:

```
_data:undefined
_metadata: {}
_ref:{}
```

Comment: Save name of the subdirectories in the fields section then get list from data instance  documentSnapshot.data!!.keys.forEach {
                    println(it)
                }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is mentioned on the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document):

> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web
>   client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of
>   administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that
>   you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider
>   restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable.

Methods to retrieve subcollections are only available on server libraries (Java, Nodes.js and Go). You can't yet list subcollections with client libraries.