# How to loop through document's sub collections in flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to loop through the sub collections which is inside documents in firestore.

This is my database structure.

[image: database structure]

I want to loop through sub collections which is inside of `batch-no-01`.

This is how I tried.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('batches').document('batch-no-01').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
     return Text('this is sample text');
  },
)
```

I'm getting the output only once. There are 2 sub collections inside `batch-no-01`, so It should iterate 2 times. But It's not working. I couldn't able to figure it out what I'm missing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no client-side API for Firestore to get a list of all subcollections. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440382/how-to-list-subcollection-on-firestore

Answer (score 0):

What is inside "batch-no-01" collection? The solution can be to transform these into documents. So after "batch-no-01" document create a collection with known name (like an ID).

Comment: Inside `batch-no-01` those are IDs of `userId`s.. I made it in this way so i see who are assign to which batch easily.. Is there any better method?