# angular firebase one to one chat. creating works, retrieving doesn't?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a one to one chat using angular and firebase and i followed a model I saw here on stackoverflow and firebase docs which was basically `collection().doc().collection().add()`

and i ended up with something like this

```
chats
  user1UID
    user1UID_user2UID
    user1UID_user3UID
  user2UID
    user1UID_user2UID
    user1UID_user3UID
  user3UID
    user1UID_user3UI
```

but for some reason trying to retrieve the chatrooms by path of uid doesn't work and returns empty

```
return this
  .afs.collection('chats')
  .doc(uid)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(r => {
      console.log(r);
    })
  );
```

i noticed the ids were italicised and looking further into it i found out it was this way because there were no fields in the docs and the docs have to be created manually to register and "not virtual". Though I'm creating the chat from code.

```
 const dRef = this.afs.collection('chats');
 const c = Promise.all([
  dRef.doc(uid).collection(`${uid}_${r_id}`).add(data),
  dRef.doc(r_id).collection(`${r_id}_${uid}`).add(r_data)
 ]);
```

i tried to see if i could set a field like 'name' while adding the collection but i don't think that's possible with `doc(uid).set({name: 'name'}).collection()` gets a warning as set is a promise. any help or guidance would really be appreciated. Please let me know what i am doing wrong and if a better and/or optimised approach is possible, i'd gladly welcome it

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @PeterHaddad retrieving the collections within the document. I'm not sure if that is possible.

Comment: if you do this `return this
  .afs.collection('chats').snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(r => {
      console.log(r);
    })
  );` what do you get?

Comment: its gets all the documents within the 'chats' collection. namely, user1UID, user2UID, user3UID. but i want to get subcollections under a specific user id

Comment: can u log the `uid` and check if the value is in the database

Comment: @PeterHaddad yup it's in the database. I tried manually adding a field and it returns the field but not the subcollections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to retrieve the subcollections of a user document with a query, which is not possible in the client-side SDKs. (See: [How to list subcollections in a Cloud Firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597126) and [How to list subcollection on firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48441118))

Your best options are to:

1. Change your data model to include the list of conversations in a **document** for the user. That way you can determine the list of conversations by just reading this document, and then read the necessary collection(s) when the user clicks on one of them.

   You'll typically want to include some primary information about each conversation in this document too, such as the last time it was updated (so you can show the most recently updated conversation first), and possibly the last message for each conversation.
2. Create a Cloud Function that returns the list of conversations, since the serve-side SDKs **do** have the feature to list collections. I'd recommend against that in this case though, as you'll still need the additional information for each conversation that I mentioned in the other option.