# How to get sub-collections of every collection in Firestore using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a task management app where every user has multiple projects (collections), inside every project there are tasks (collections), and inside every task there are sub-tasks.

I was able to retrieve all the projects using this code:

```
User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
CollectionReference projects = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection("projects");
```

But my question is how can I get all the tasks and sub-tasks (if they exist) from every project and list them in a StreamBuilder?

Here's my current code:

```
Flexible(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: projects.snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }

                return new ListView(
                  children:
                      snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Text(document.data['project_name']),
                      subtitle: new Text(document.data['project_description']),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

If the project has tasks I want to display them below the project description, and if the task has sub-tasks I want to show them below its parent task.

Comment: You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) which explains how to retrieve the list of subcollections of a document with a Cloud Function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're essentially asking how to list nested subcollections, which is not possible for web and mobile clients.  See also:

- [How to list subcollections in a Cloud Firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document)
- [How to list subcollection on firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440382/how-to-list-subcollection-on-firestore)

Also, all Firestore queries are shallow, meaning they only consider documents in one collection at a time.  There are no deep or recursive queries.

Consider instead maintaining the list of projects in a document that you can `get()` directly.  You can use that list to then query each subcollection directly.

Answer (score 2):

There are different kind of implementations for this scenario, basically subcollections are located under one single document, the query identifies a group of documents, when you know that the query only identifies one document, the Firestore client doesn't know that, and even if it did, it doesn,t know the full path for that document.

You need to execute a query for getting individual documents, and then you can get the subcollection of each one.

You can find a good example using flutter [here](https://medium.com/@borsezf2/sub-collections-list-from-firestore-d6c6e029bed3).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and used bloc provider alongside streams,
I first created a model for Json parsing (In my case I had an app whereby users can create campaigns, these campaigns were saved as a sub-collection in the UserData collection, the document IDs were the userID from FirebaseAuth(now User in flutter migration). The objective was to loop through UserData collection for each user's subcollection (UserCampaigns) and retrieve all of them and display in the UI with bloc. userCampaignRepository:

```
    List<UserCampaignModel> UserCampaignList = [];
CreateListofAllUserCampaigns(QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {
var docs = snapshot.docs;
for (var Doc in docs) {
  UserCampaignList.add(
      UserCampaignModel.fromEntity(UserCampaignEntity.fromSnapshot(Doc)));
}
return UserCampaignList;
```

}

```
Stream<List<UserCampaignModel>> getListUserCampaigns() async* {
final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserData');
final List list_of_users = await collection.get().then((value) => value.docs);
for (int i = 0; i < list_of_users.length; i++) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("UserData")
      .doc(list_of_users[i].id.toString())
      .collection("UserCampaigns")
      .snapshots()
      .listen(CreateListofAllUserCampaigns);
}
yield UserCampaignList;
```

}

In the bloc: I have 2 events, one to initiate the Load of Events by listening to the stream and calling the loader event.

```
     if (event is InitiateLoadOfAllUserCampaignsEvent) {
  yield AllUserCampaignsState.initial();
  try {
    
    _userCampaignSubscription?.cancel();
    _userCampaignSubscription = _userCampaignRepository
        .getListUserCampaigns()
        .listen((allCampaigns) {
          print("Load event is called");
      add(
        LoadAllUserCampaignsEvent(allUserCampaigns: allCampaigns),
      );
      
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print("error is ${e}");
    yield AllUserCampaignsState.allUserCampaignLoadFailure();
  }
} else if (event is LoadAllUserCampaignsEvent) {
  yield* _mapLoadAllUserCampaignsEventToState(event);
}}}
```