# How to get all sub collection ids of a Firestore document in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to get a list of all sub collection ids of a Firestore document in Flutter?
I know that there are ways of doing this in other programming languages, but I haven't been able to find any information about this for Flutter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819670/how-to-get-sub-collections-of-every-collection-in-firestore-using-flutter/6395978)1 . I think this answer your question.

Comment: See the duplicate answer, which was pointed out by As Syed Ahmad. But also see this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) which explains how to a Callable Cloud Function that will send back to your Flutter app the lists of subcollections. As a matter of fact, while retrieving a list of (sub)collections is not possible with the **mobile/web client libraries** it is possible with the Admin SDK (which is used by Cloud Functions).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec It looks like you closed against the wrong link (not sure what went wrong there), so I updated that.