# How to show collection list in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There are documents in the collection,

There is a collection in that document,

The collection contains documents, and the documents contain values.

.

This is the structure.

Collection> Document> **Collection**> Document> id:aa / age:20 /....

.

How do I see the collection list contained in a document in the first collection?

I want to know the list of collections in the 3rd digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list subcollections using server-side SDKs, for example in Node.JS (from [the doc](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections-examples)):

```
firestore.doc('col/doc').listCollections().then(collections => {
  for (let collection of collections) {
    console.log(`Found subcollection with id: ${collection.id}`);
  }
});
```

On the other hand, client and mobile SDKs cannot list subcollections, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48441118/6016470), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46596532/6016470). You would need to either store the subcollections' names in a document field, or use predictable subcollection names.